# What software/package can be used to draw something like this?

Tags: diagrams

I refer to Allen Hatcher's famous book on Algebraic Topology:
http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch1.pdf

What software or LaTeX package can be used to draw those figures?
Or are those best hand drawn?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you looked around in all the questions marked with the diagrams tag? That should point you in directions.

Comment: tikz is the obvious route

Comment: pstricks and its many extensions should work fine too.

Comment: You could do it in Inkscape and convert, although LaTeX doesn’t support SVG natively.